# XAML/UWP TextBlock Issues

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

Im having a bit of a weird bug with a Textblock pane that ive got nested within a PaneFooter.

it looks like this currently:

[image]

Essentially the symbol icon and Textblock are overlapping at the moment.
Was wondering if you could help. Heres my XAML for this particular section

```
            <NavigationView.PaneFooter>
                <Button x:Name="ChangeUser" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockButtonStyle}" Foreground="#b880fc" >
                    <RelativePanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <TextBlock Padding="3"/>
                        <SymbolIcon Symbol="Contact" />
                        <StackPanel>                            
                                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center">      
                                        Change User     
                                </TextBlock>                                                                                 
                        </StackPanel>
                    </RelativePanel>
                </Button>                  
            </NavigationView.PaneFooter>            
        </mux:NavigationView>            
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

The alignement isnt doing anything and was wondering if theres anyway of adding a margin from the left hand side to create spacing from the Symbol Icon. I have no idea how to even begin working around this currently. Its just a bit weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't use RelativePanel unless you know how to use it, it is good for complex responsive design but for simple layout like this just use `StackPanel` with horizontal orientation.

```
<Button x:Name="ChangeUser" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockButtonStyle}" Foreground="#b880fc" >
     <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <SymbolIcon Symbol="Contact" Margin="4"/>                                                  
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">      
                                    Change User     
            </TextBlock>                                                                               
     </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Also you don't need extra textblock with padding 3 and that extra stackpanel around your textblock, please look at the code I provided above.

Comment: Thank you for this. It was super helpful. Your time is appreciated